# Ruby permutation code challenge

Tags: ruby, permutation

I'm learning ruby and have come across a code challenge that I've been struggling with for the past couple days. Was hoping someone here could provide insight.

**The task**

is to write a function that prints to the standard output (stdout) the number of unique possible configurations (As, Bs, Cs) which can be used to serve exactly N visitors.

As represents the number of users from location a we choose to serve

Bs represents the number of users from location b we choose to serve

Cs represents the number of users from location c we choose to serve

**Note that your function will receive the following arguments:**

**a**

which is an integer representing the number of users from location a

**b**

which is an integer representing the number of users from location b

**c**

which is an integer representing the number of users from location c

**n**

which is an integer representing the number of users our servers can serve

**Data constraints**

the values for a, b, c will be in the [0 .. 100] range

n will always be smaller than the sum of a, b, and c

**Example**

```
a = 1

b = 1

c = 1

n = 1
```

**Possible solutions**

```
[1,0,0] [0,1,0] [0,0,1]
```

**Answer**

```
3
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which part do you need help with?

Comment: @minitech I'm wondering if anyone can explain the problem and solution to me as I'm pretty confused. I'd be just as happy with someone pointing me in the right direction towards solving if myself as well though.

Comment: Where did you find this challenge from?

Comment: I found the challenge on a learning website called talentbuddy, I emailed the founder and asked on the community but didn't hear back.

Answer (score 0):

Each solution consists of 3 numbers. The first number must be in the range from 0 to a, second number in the range from 0 to b, third number in the range 0 to c.

The sum of the three numbers in each solution must be equal to n.

You have to find out how many unique solutions exist.

Another example:

```
a = b = c = n = 2
```

Solutions:

```
[2, 0, 0] [1, 1, 0] [0, 2, 0] [0, 1, 1] [0, 0, 2] [1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You could do that recursively:

def combos(users, remaining_assignments)
  mx = [users.first, remaining_assignments].min
  if users.size==1
    (0..mx).to_a.map { |e| [e] }
  else
    (0..mx).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
      combos(users[1..-1], remaining_assignments-i).each { |e| a << [i] + e } }
  end
end

users = [3,2,4]
remaining_assignments = 6

combos(users, remaining_assignments)
  #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4],
  #    [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4],
  #    [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4],
  #    [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 4],
  #    [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4],
  #    [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 0, 0],
  #    [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3], [2, 0, 4], [2, 1, 0],
  #    [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1],
  #    [2, 2, 2], [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 2], [3, 0, 3],
  #    [3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1]]
```

If the sum of the numbers of users served at each location must *equal* (rather than being no greater than) `remaining_assignments`, modify `combos` as follows:

```
def combos(users, remaining_assignments)
  if users.size==1
    [[remaining_assignments]]
  else
    mn = [0, remaining_assignments - users[1..-1].reduce(:+)].max
    mx = [users.first, remaining_assignments].min
    (mn..mx).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
       combos(users[1..-1], remaining_assignments-i).each { |e| a << [i] + e } }
  end
end

users = [3,2,4]
remaining_assignments = 6

combos(users, remaining_assignments)
  #=> [[0, 2, 4], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 0, 4], [2, 1, 3],
  #    [2, 2, 2], [3, 0, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Alternatively, if `remaining_assignments` is not much less than `users.size`, or if efficiency is not a concern, you could simplify by generating all the combinations then throw out the ones for which the sum of the numbers of users exceeds `remaining_assignments`:

```
def combos(users, remaining_assignments)
   a = users.map { |u| (0..u).to_a }
   a.shift.product(*a).select { |b| b.reduce(:+) <= remaining_assignments }
end
```

Remove `<` if the total numbers of users selected at each locations must equal `remaining_assignments`.